# Eclipse Refactor all method call

Tags: java, eclipse

In eclipse java i used a static method call in several places.

```
A.method1();
```

How can i change these all calls in one change using refacor to `B.method2()`

Answer (score 2):

Solution based on code refactoring called "Inline ...", it replaces every method call with its implementation.
Example:
Before we have: `obj1.method1(){};` and `obj2.method2(obj1){ obj1.method1(); };`

After applying eclipse refactoring "Inline ..." we will have every call of `obj2.method2(obj1);` replaced with call `obj1.method1()`;

That was easy!

Answer (score 0):

I think the easy way is by press ctrl+f to open find/replace window, then you can replace your code in one shot by clicking "Replace All" like this:

[image]

if you are trying to replace the signature only not the method name then you can do so by alt+shift+c [here is a reference](http://www.eclipseonetips.com/2010/02/10/change-a-methods-arguments-across-multiple-classes-in-eclipse/):

if you are trying to change the method name, then go to class which you defined the method in it the press alt+shift+r to rename the method declaration in that class and everywhere you call it.
and [here is a reference:](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-menu-refactor.htm)

Comment: But if we have arguments for these methods. this is not possible

Comment: just change the name, and leave the rest, A.method1 without "()" with B.method2

Comment: Find and replace will not change method calls in other code places. Refactoring is not a text editing it is a softdev technique!